# After reloading my tableView with content, it still appears greyed-out until I tap it..why?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar, reloaddata

After retrieving search results from a UISearchBar, the results appear in my tableview correctly, but the view is 'greyed out' (see image below)..Any help on this is appreciated, I can't find a solution the Apple documentation.

This is my code that is fired upon hitting the Search button:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
isSearchOn = YES;
canSelectRow = YES;
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

CityLookup *cityLookup = [[CityLookup alloc] findCity:searchBar.text];

if ([cityLookup.citiesList count] > 0) {
    tableCities = cityLookup.citiesList;
}

[cityLookup release];

isSearchOn = NO;

self.searchBar.text=@"";

[self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

And this is how the table view is being refreshed:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

NSString *cellValue = [tableCities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the full package with a `UISearchDisplayController` the following line should remove the search interface:

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

If you are not using `UISearchDisplayController` I would recommend checking it out and see if it doesn't suit your needs.

*Remark: There is nothing in your posted code that would remove whatever view you have used to grey out the table view. So if you are not using `UISearchDisplayController` look in the code that displays the search interface to see what you need to do to remove it.*

Answer (score 0):

Your not hiding your search bar when hitting search, try:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: that just hides the navigation bar, not the SearchBar..the table still has the greyed out background..

Comment: Oops, try dismissing your search bar then.

Comment: I know, that's why it's so frustrating...I will try re-writing from scratch to see if I missed something